# Placing 2 divs next to each other with the left filling the space

Tags: html, css, web, styles

How can I place two `div`s right next to each other (left and right) in order that the left `div` auto sizes depending on how wide the right `div` is.

So for example if the right container is `100px` wide and the right `div` in the container is `10px` wide ,then the left `div` is `90px` wide. OR if the right `div` is `40px` wide then the left is `60px` wide.

Thanks

Comment: put a width="auto" on the left and then set the right's width with javascript. make the divs style="display:inline"

Answer (score 3):

This is a trick I use a lot

```
<style>
    .sidebar {
        width: 600px;
        float: left;
        background: #00ff00;
    }

    .content {
        margin-left: 610px;
        background: #ff0000;
    }
</style>

<div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
</div>

<div class="content">
    content
</div>
```

You set the width of one element and float it, then you force the element you want to sit beside it into the gap by putting a margin on it the same width as the floating element.

Word of warning: In this example,  the sidebar element MUST appear first in your source code.

You can adjust the width of the columns dynamically by changing the width of one element and the margin of the other element.

Save the source to an html file on your destop and have a play around with it to figure out how it works.

Comment: This is a new option, but I would prefer it the opposite way which doesnt seem to work?

Comment: Change sidebar to float to the right, and change content margin-left to margin-right. You may need to change the order of sidebar and content.. ie.. put the sidebar div AFTER the content DIV.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the comment above.  Just make sure that you `float: right;` the div that you want to the right side of the screen.  I would have left this as an additional comment, but do not have enough rep to do so.

```
<style>
    .left {
        width: auto;
    }

    .right {
        width: 100px;
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```